# how to update a database table with a list of data

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle12c

Say I have a database table with two columns - `vehicle` and `location`.

Each `vehicle` has many `locations`.

When my program receives a message containing a list of locations per vehicle, I could do any of the following:

1. `Delete` all locations for the vehicle and loop through the message to re-`insert` them all (inefficient)
2. `Select` the locations for the vehicle from the database, loop through the message and create a list of those locations that are in the database but not the message, and those that are in the message but not the database. Delete (`DELETE WHERE IN...`) those that are in the db but not the message, and `insert` those that are in the message but not the database.

This is where my knowledge of SQL fails me. Is there a more efficient way (i.e. less SQL statements, less db time, less locking) for doing this (I can't do stored procedures)?

My instinct tells me I must be able to do `DELETE WHERE NOT IN...`, to save having to `select` from the database in option 2 - but then I still have to `select` to know which additional ones to insert. Is there any `INSERT` equivalent - `INSERT {THIS LIST OF locations} ALL WITH {this vehicle}`, perhaps? Or is there a standard piece of synchronisation logic that is typically used in this kind of situation?

Comment: Use exists or joins, is vehicle unique?  So join old_vehicles to new_vehicles where old_vehicles.vehicle=new_vehiclesvehicle and do what you need to.

Comment: yeah, vehicle is (should be- not enforced) unique.

Comment: So, you can delete an inner join on vehicle {and location???}, then insert the rest if I am reading right :o)

Comment: wouldn't that result in some records being deleted and then reinserted; if they're already in the database table?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit brute force, that way.  Look at using Joins or Exists, I only had a quick stab at it in Access. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have vehicle `V1` with locations `A`, `B` and `X` and vehicle `V2` with locations `B` and `Q`. The message is for vehicle `V1` with locations `A`, `Y`.

For `delete` part you could use this:

```
delete from t where veh = 'V1' and loc not in ('A', 'Y');
```

and for `insert` this `merge`:

```
merge into t 
using (select 'V1' veh, 'A' loc from dual union all
       select 'V1' veh, 'Y' loc from dual) s
on (t.veh = s.veh and t.loc = s.loc)
when not matched then insert values (s.veh, s.loc);
```

Location `A` remained untouched, `B` and `X` were deleted by `delete`, `Y` was added by `merge`. If you have more columns in table you can do whole operation in one `merge`, but I don't know if it would be faster, because it would require join in source query.

---

**Edit:**
You have to build somehow your "message" into data structure readable by Oracle. Maybe messages are already stored in some table, maybe you can use temp structure. You didn't precise that in your question.
I gave you an example working on dual, because I had to construct statements somehow. For `V1(A, B, C)` and `V3(X, Y)` you can do `union all` 5 times or use shorter syntax:

```
select 'V1' veh, column_value loc from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A', 'B', 'C')) union all
select 'V3' veh, column_value loc from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('X', 'Y'))
```

`sys.odcivarchar2list` is an Oracle predefined type, you can also define your own (`create type locations as table of varchar2(100)`) and use it.

Anyway, run `delete` twice for each vehicle:

```
delete from t where veh = `V1` and loc not in ('A', 'B', 'C');
delete from t where veh = `V3` and loc not in ('X', 'Y');
```

and `merge` once:

```
merge into t 
using (
    select 'V1' veh, column_value loc from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A', 'B', 'C')) 
    union all
    select 'V3' veh, column_value loc from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('X', 'Y'))) s
on (t.veh = s.veh and t.loc = s.loc)
when not matched then insert values (s.veh, s.loc);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, if the message had a lot of locations, would I need to build up the `using` clause with a lot of `union all`s? - I guess I'm asking, how does your example with two locations extrapolate out? Do you just keep putting `from dual union all`between each entry?